# Проблема с функционалом отзывов на сайте

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<form action="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-comments-post.php" id="commentform" method="post">
  <input  name="author" id="author" value="" type="text" size="30" alt="Name" placeholder="Имя" required />
  <input name="email" id="email" value="" type="text" size="30" alt="Email" style="display: none;" />
  <textarea name="comment" id="comment" rows="5" cols="5"  placeholder="Отзыв" required></textarea>
  <input  type="submit" value="Отправить" />
  <?php 
    comment_id_fields();
    do_action('comment_form', $post->ID); 
    ?>
</form>
```

Сделал такую ​​форму для страницы отзывов, но все отзывы привязываются по id к постам которые есть у меня в блоге. Как привязать комментарии к странице? Чтобы комментировались не посты, а страница. Сайт на Wordpress

Comment: Заменить $post->ID на $page->ID. Вряд ли тут можно сказать что-то более вразумительное.

Comment: @Эникейщик а разве проблема не в comment_id_fields? Она генерирует скрытые поля в одном из которых отправляет id поста. Я сделал так как вы сказали, но это не допомогло. Нет ли аналогичной команды comment_id_fields, только для id страницы?

Comment: вы в `comment_id_fields()` можете передать id страницы и по умолчанию туда попадает id из глобальной переменной $post.По вашему коду не понятно где размещается форма, но по всей видимости вы эту форму вызываете в цикле или на странице поста, вот и получаете id поста,а не страницы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перед формой нужно добавить wp_reset_query() чтобы аннулировать данные последнего запроса, созданного для использования в произвольном Цикле WordPress который выводил посты.